# how to do maths in mongoose.js query

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I have multiple rows and I would like to return this data as a league table and ordered as a football league table.

My data is in multiple rows for each game played as:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("55d0f8a6bd0782b480dc4941"),
    "venue" : "h",
    "game_id" : ObjectId("55d0f8a6bd0782b480dc48f9"),
    "date" : ISODate("2015-04-25T14:00:00.000Z"),
    "gd" : 0,
    "ga" : 1,
    "gf" : 1,
    "points" : 1,
    "team_id" : ObjectId("55d0f8a6bd0782b480dc48f1"),
    "__v" : 0
}
```

I can see no way to do maths inside of the query and return the calculated values of all the points for a given `team_id`.

Is there a `Math` in `Mongoose` like group in `mySQL`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes there is, you can use http://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#aggregate_Aggregate-group and $sum http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/ to get the sum of points on each team

```
 your-model-name.aggregate([
    {
        $group: {
            _id: '$team_id',  
            total: {$sum: "$points"}
        }
    }
], function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
        // an error ....
    } else {
        // your result
    }
});
```

Comment: So many times I say mind blown on here :p But once again mind blown. Funny how I couldn't find this easily on the documentation :( But thank you so much. This will keep me busy for a long time now :)

Comment: But now I wonder if I can get it to order it without having to manually do it after i've got the results

Comment: add ```{ "$sort": { "total": -1 } }``` to sort your results